# Angular router: named outlets does not seem to work with relative routes nor in lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-router, angular10

I have some problems with the angular router and named outlets.
I have a list of members, and want to edit a clicked member on the same page in a named router outlet.
And I would like to have the member handling in a lazy loaded module.

[StackBlitz](https://angular-ivy-ebjcn2.stackblitz.io)

It works when the module is not lazy loaded.
The template looks like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let member of members">
...
<a [routerLink]="['/home/member', {outlets: {right: ['memberedit', member._id]}}]"> Edit</a>
```

And the routes array:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'member', component: MemberComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'memberlist', component: MemberListComponent,
            resolve: { resolvedListData: MemberListResolver },
          },
          {
            path: 'memberedit/:id', component: MemberEditComponent,
            resolve: { resolvedMember: MemberResolver }
            outlet: 'right',
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

When I try to remove he reference to /home/member in order to prepare for lazy loading, it no longer works:

I have tried with:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {right: ['memberedit', member._id]}}]">Edit</a>
```

This doesn't work, I think this is a known error, the router constructs this URL with a single slash after memberlist:

`/home/member/memberlist/(right:memberedit/5f39748b88457a30e32e909d)`

And I have tried with:

```
<a [routerLink]="['../', {outlets: {right: ['memberedit', member._id]}}]"> Edit</a>
```

It works the first time I click on a member. And gives this URL:

`/home/member/(memberlist//right:memberedit/5f39748b88457a30e32e909d)`

The second time I click on another member I get this error:

```
Error: Two segments cannot have the same outlet name: 'memberedit/5f4227887687e3162d94f5a3' and 'memberedit/5f39748b88457a30e32e909d'.
```

And the URL is:

```
/home/member/(/(right:memberedit/5f4227887687e3162…f5a3)//right:memberedit/5f39748b88457a30e32e909d)"
```

I have also tried with:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: ['memberlist'], right: ['memberedit', member._id]}}]">Edit</a>
<a [routerLink]="['../', {outlets: {primary: ['memberlist'], right: ['memberedit', member._id]}}]">Edit</a>
```

Without any luck.

I have tried with "full pathname" in the lazy loaded module that doesn't work.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home/member', {outlets: {right: ['memberedit', member._id]}}]"> Edit</a>
```

Gives:

```
url: "/home/member/(memberlist//right:memberedit/5f39748b88457a30e32e909d)", urlAfterRedirects: "/home/member"
```

And I have tried all the above in the lazy loaded module.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz demo or something similar? It would be much easier to find a solution

Comment: How do you reach the `memberlist` route? Have you tried something like this? `[routerLink]=['/home/member', { outlets: { primary: 'memberlist' } }]`, Ultimately, you could try using `Router.navigateByUrl('/home/member/(memberlist)')`.

Comment: The memberlist is reached with <a [routerLink]="['memberlist']">

Comment: It would be easier to find the problem in a StackBlitz or something

Comment: StackBlitz: `https://angular-ivy-ebjcn2.stackblitz.io`

Comment: So looks like it works with `/home/member', { outlets: ...`, right? Are there other problems?

Comment: Yes it does not work when the module is lazy loaded,
And the relative route does not work either. I have updated StackBlitz with a lazy loaded module

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with the lazy-loaded module this way:

#### lazy-member-routing.module

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    // {
    //     path: '', component: LazyMemberComponent,
    //     children: [
            {
                path: 'list', component: ListComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'edit/:id', component: EditComponent,
                outlet: 'lazyright',
            },
    //     ]
    // },
];
```

#### app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'member', component: MemberComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'list', component: ListComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'edit/:id', component: EditComponent,
            outlet: 'right'
          }
        ]
      },
      { 
        path: 'lazymember', 
        loadChildren: () => import('./lazy-member/lazy-member.module').then(m => m.LazyMemberModule),
        component: LazyMemberComponent,
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

#### list.component.html

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/home/lazymember', {outlets: {lazyright: ['edit', member.id]}}]">Edit works - No, no longer</a>
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ddvgim?file=src%2Fapp%2Flazy-member%2Flist%2Flist.component.html)

---

It did not work initially with `path: '', component: LazyMemberComponent,` because of how Angular Router resolves navigations. Basically, for each child of an `UrlSegmentGroup`, it will loop through the current routes array and will try to find a match.

For example, the main `UrlSegmentGroup` would look like this:

```js
{
   children: {
     primary: {
      children: {
         lazyright: {
            children: {},
            segments: ['edit', '2']
         },
         primary: {
            children: {},
            segments: ['list'],
         }
      }
      segments: ['home', 'lazymember']
     } 
   },
   segments: []
}
```

Then,

- `'home'` segment will match `path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,`
- `'lazymember'` segment will match `path: 'lazymember' ...`
- now we have `lazyright` and `primary`, both of which must find their match in the current routes array, which is now `[{ path: '', component: LazyMemberComponent, children: [...] }]`; this is the reason it did not work before

If you'd like to read a bit more about `UrlTree`s and `UrlSegmentGroup`s, I've written an [article](https://github.com/Andrei0872/my-dev-notes/blob/master/notebooks/ng/router/urltree.md) on this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this when I return from vacation.